# How to check if image url has been loaded with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, thumbnails, jquery-load

I have this code here where I have a slider with thumbnails and the sliders large image takes it's next `attr('src')` from the click on a thumb, but I'd like to change that src only when the image has loaded. This is the source that I've come up with so far:

```
$('.thumb').click(function(){
    topImageSrc = $(this).data("bigimage");

    $(topImageSrc).load(function(){
        coverMain.attr('src',topImageSrc);
        main.fadeOut("slow");
    })
});
```

Sadly this doesn't work as the `topImageSrc` is just a path variable to the  large image, like so: `/uploads/largeimages/pic1.jpg`

How could I force it to load and then check if it's done, after that - apply the new image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do it like this:**

```
$('.thumb').click(function () {
    topImageSrc = $(this).data("bigimage");
    var topImage = $('<img>').attr('src', topImageSrc);
    $(topImage).load(function () {
        coverMain.attr('src', topImageSrc);
        main.fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

This creates an image (without appending it anywhere), sets its source to the `topImageSrc` URL and checks for the `load` event.

Comment: I suppose this should work, but I get `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /uploads/largeimages/pic1.jpg`

Comment: Are you adding that URL directly? Seems like you're missing quotes* around the URL.